# Android Studio preview fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

i have the following layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/what_did_you_eat"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".AddFoodActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

`FrameLayout` will contain a dynamic added `fragment`, is there a way to preview in the editor the `fragment` ?
Like we can do when using a **<fragment>** tag with the **`tools:layout`** attribute ?

Comment: In acepted answer is redirect ot docs. I looked to tools docs but I don't see the aswer. Can you post exact solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it would be useful, there's nothing in [the current tools docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes) that suggests this is possible.

Comment: You can nest `fragment` tag under the `FrameLayout` just like described here in the Layout chapter https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html
it will work