# Layout editor: How to show layout in framelayout container?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, graphical-layout-editor

I have a layout defined in XML as root ConstraintLayout that contains 4 empty frameLayouts for dynamically inflating fragments. In order to have a better design experience in the layout editor (Android Studio), is there a way to show/mimic the intended layouts in each of these framelayouts?

This question is not about loading a fragment in a container dynamically (in the code), I am looking for a solution that will allow me to load a layout in a container/Framelayout in the Layout Editor!

Comment: FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID, newFragment).commit();

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge and answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586708/android-studio-preview-fragment) it is not possible. However in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675456/use-layout-editor-effectively-on-layouts-with-non-static-fragments) you can find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround using `android:visibilty:"gone"`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/doNotUseThisPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
        <include
            layout="@layout/designTimeLayout" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```